# Remove part URL before second last slash in PHP

Tags: php, string

How can I remove the part in my URL that is before the second last slash?
My URL is this:

```
http://antwerp.test/nl/aanbod/activiteiten/kunst/the-world-of-steve-mccurry/the-world-of-steve-mccurry/activity-mccurry/
```

So I want to remove "the-world-of-steve-mccurry/" the second time it appears. The URL should be:

```
http://antwerp.test/nl/aanbod/activiteiten/kunst/the-world-of-steve-mccurry/activity-mccurry/
```

Comment: Just this one very specific case? Or are there a bunch of these? If it's a bunch, is the rule always "the second to last" or is it "remove the duplicated bit" or something else?

Comment: I have thousands of these URL's that needs te be altered. But it's always the same. Other example: 
http://antwerp.test/nl/aanbod/musea/museumtickets/museum-mayer/museum-mayer/museum-mayer-van-den-bergh-tijdelijke-expositie-ontmoet-henriette/ should be http://antwerp.test/nl/aanbod/musea/museumtickets/museum-mayer/museum-mayer-van-den-bergh-tijdelijke-expositie-ontmoet-henriette/

Comment: If it's the second-to-last every time, use `explode` with `/` as the delineator, remove the second-to-last array item, and re-`implode` it.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can explode the url by "/" , then remove the mentioned part , then implode again :

```php
  function sms($url)
    {
        substr($url,-1) === "/"? $position = 3:$position = 2; // decide if URL ends with `/` or not 
        $partsArray = explode('/',$url);
        $partsArrayCount = count($partsArray);
        $toDelete = $partsArray[$partsArrayCount-$position]; // get the part that you want to delete 
        unset($partsArray[$partsArrayCount-3]);
        $result = implode("/",$partsArray);
        return $result;
    }
```